# UILabel in UICollectionView span over two or more cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I know how to program a label within a cell (see below label2), my problem is, I want to build a calendar and when e.g.I have an appointment over two days I need a label which spans over two cells (see image, label 1) Any idea how this can be achieved? Every help is more than appreciated!!

[image]

When I use the following code the second image shows that the label is hidden by the following cell(you can see the small green line between the cells):

```
 let myLabel = UILabel()
    myLabel.clipsToBounds = false
    myLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cell.addSubview(myLabel)
    myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    myLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: desiredWidth).isActive = true
    myLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    let margins = cell.layoutMarginsGuide
    myLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
    myLabel.text = "Appointment"
```

[image]

Comment: It works, as soon as I draw it from the last cell which should be overlapped(i.e. add a constraint in the last cell to the right). Thanks to Razi, who put me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first you have to uncheck clips to bound for the cell in Storyboard or you can do that in

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
  // So that the label can go out of bound
  cell?.clipsToBounds = false
  cell?.label.clipsToBounds = false

  .
  .
  .

  return cell
}
```

Now you can either use a logic with the constraint to achieve what you want in the InterfaceBuilder

Or

You can change the frame of the Label in cellForItemAt something like this

```
// Change desiredWidth according to you needs
let desiredWidth = 1000

cell?.wordlabel.frame = CGRect(origin: (cell?.wordlabel.frame.origin)! , size: CGSize(width: desiredWidth, height: 30))
```

**EDIT**

You can adjust the size of your cell by:

```
extension YourViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)

    let size = (data[indexPath.row] as NSString).size(withAttributes:[NSAttributedString.Key.font: font])

    // Add your logic here for the desired cell width
    let additionalpadding: CGFloat = 1000
    return CGSize(width: size.width + additionalpadding, height: 30)
}

}
```

Comment: thx for your answer, but I do not get it to work. clipsToBounds is set to false by default, and the problem is, (I think) that the following new cell is drawn after the label is drawn and then overlapping the label, so it is not to be seen. I added the code and the result

Comment: @Red You are right the next cell will be drawn on top of that but you can now either set the background of the cell to .clear or can adjust the size of you cell, i am adding a snippet for the later in the question. But this all depends upon what you want.

Comment: Thx for your comment. To change the size ion the cell doesn't help, the idea is, to have the label span over two cells. But you put me in the right direction, I simply draw the label from the LAST cell ist overlaps, and then it works!! Thank you very much for your help. Would love to accept your answer as it put me in the right direction - would that be correct?

Comment: @Red Gald to help